# Visual Studio 2015: Update 2: Package didn't load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using MSVS 2015 update 2 and my OS is Windows 10 Home 64bit.

I'm new to MSVS 2015 and I don't know how to resolve this issue.
Everytime I try to launch VS2015 application, it tells me that some or the other package didn't load correctly and restarting might fix the issue.

I tried searching on google for the solution. They said that delete all the files in this folder: "C:\Users\Nachiket C Kare\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache"

I'm keep deleting the files in that folder before launching VS every time but it still says that some package didn't load correctly. This is so annoying and there must be a permanent way to fix this problem.
Please help.

Thanks!

PS: I believe I have seen the following packages missing prompt: python manager, windows form designer manager and xaml designer manager

PPS: Yet to write a single line of code :D Facing these issues during project creation and at launch of application.

Comment: Have you tried repairing your VS2015? Windows key->type "Apps & features"->find VS2015->click it->choose "Modify" wait for the "Repair" option to be available.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks! Will try doing that..